# Any alternative to Wine

Tags: windows, software-recommendation, wine, alternative

I'm looking for an application to do the same sort of thing as Wine: Running Windows applications on Ubuntu.

Is there any alternative application instead of install/using Wine?

Comment: Generally the answer to this will probably be no, but if you tell us more about what you need--for example, what applications you need to run--then it might be possible for someone to suggest an alternative.

Comment: Why not Wine itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no there is no alternative to Wine except installing Windows. So either install Windows in a partition or run it under a virtual environment.

The general answer will be no, as stated above. But there are Ubuntu compatible alternatives for many programs which means there might be a native program you can install instead.

Answer (score 2):

there is CrossOver. it's a fork of wine, well tested and supported but not free
https://www.codeweavers.com/products/crossover-linux/.

otherwise you have VM solutions (virtualbox, vmware...) but not the same as wine

Comment: Which is bigger package? Is it WINE or CROSSOVER?